# Set and change constant variables in hardhat tests

Tags: javascript, hardhat, testing, constant

I have a constant variable in my solidity:

```js
address private constant MY_ADDRESS = 0x000000000
```

However, `MY_ADDRESS` may change for my tests, but in my contract I want to keep it as a constant.

How do I address this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to swap out the byte code during your test, and then set the code.

```js
const CONSTANT_VARIABLE_TO_REPLACE = "0xC1E088fC1323b20BCBee9bd1B9fC9546db5624C5"

async function swapOutConstant(contractAddress, newConstantVariable) {
  let contractJson = fs.readFileSync(
    `./artifacts/contracts/MyContract.sol/MyContract.json`
  );

  const constantToReplaceSubstring = CONSTANT_VARIABLE_TO_REPLACE.substring(2);

  await network.provider.send("hardhat_setCode", [
    contractAddress,
    JSON.parse(contractJson).deployedBytecode.replaceAll(
      constantToReplaceSubstring.toLowerCase(),
      newConstantVariable.substring(2).toLowerCase()
    ),
  ]);

  const myContract = await ethers.getContractAt("MyContract", contractAddress);
  return myContract;
}
```

Then, import this function in your test and set the contract you want to test to it.

In this example, we use `substring` because the bytecode of an address doesn't have the `0x`, so we lop it off.

Note this gets harder when working with numbers that might be duplicated. It's easy with addresses since it's unlikely that address will show up in your bytecode when not referring to the address you're trying to replace.

Probably the ugliest thing on the planet. I think we should make a hardhat issue.

Comment: Thanks a ton for sharing this! Very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the value of a constant as it's value is hardcoded.

See [this](https://solidity-by-example.org/constants/).

Can you maybe set MY_ADDRESS in the constructor so it's dynamically set for each test?

Comment: But in our tests we want to be able to. See below.

Comment: Did you just make a post to answer your own question?

Comment: I do it all the time. Anytime I web search something and someone else hasn't asked the question, I make sure to document it. This way, when I learn something, the whole world can learn it as well instead of having to go through the same process of trial and error I did. I highly recommend everyone take up this practice.